# Link a different page in JSP and retain current Spring Security Session

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, spring-security

When the user logs in to my webapp using Spring Security, he is redirected to a certain JSP webpage and his user context is active (logged-in session). Now, on this page, after a link or button is clicked I want to display to him on the same webpage a parsed JSON data from another URL, but when I access this page with JSON data using:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

this page with JSON is accessed without using his session and the JSON data cannot be accessed.

To sum up, my problem is: how to access another webpage using JSP in the same current user (Spring Security) session?

Comment: save you data that you want to display in a session variable

Comment: The problem is that the JSON data must be downloaded from another url, which should be accessed from the same session using jsp, but it is being accessed in a new session.I have no idea why, but when I try to display data from another url on the same jsp, where the user is redirected after successful login and the session is working there, before the data is shown new session is created in order to access another url.

Comment: For a start get rid of code out of JSP and use servlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access a JSP or Servlet from your browser, there is a session between your browser and your webapp.

But what your are doing here opening a URLConnection from your Java code (no matter this code is in a JSP or in Servlet, it's the same on runtime) is requesting a resource from the server itself to a resource in the same server. That's it, your Java code is opening a new session to the server. As the JSON your are requesting is session dependent (that's what you said), the replies would be different.

If you have a kind of manager app (as psi-probe for Tomcat for example) in session management you could see that there are at least two sessions alive in your application context, one for the browser session and another one for the Java connection to the server JSON resource.

If you really need to get that json from the same session you are using when calling the jsp from the browser, you could access that JSON resource from it using javascript. There are other alternatives as well, as call directly the Java class that returns the JSON resource via java import instead of calling it as a URL.

Comment: Very good idea to do the JSON request client side. If you have to request your JSON server side, you should look into copying the session cookie across to the client that does the backend-side request. For this have to use a more sophisticated library than java.net.URL, e.g. apache HttpClient.